# if $AA^*$ = $A + A^*$ then $A$ is normal

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthonormal

I have been trying to prove the following:

if $AA^*$ = $A + A^*$ then $A$ is normal (meaning : $AA^* = A^*A$).

I have literally tried everything possible; I can't come up with proof.

Any ideas?

Comment: I believe that the exact same question has been asked very recently

Comment: @Jakobian $A^*$ denotes the conjugate-transpose, not simply the conjugate

Comment: In any case, one approach is to simply expand the product
$$
(A - I)(A - I)^*.
$$

Comment: This follows from the result in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2242629/if-ab-ab-then-ab-ba/2242650#2242650)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that if $A^*+A=AA^*$ then $A$ is normal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3740308/prove-that-if-aa-aa-then-a-is-normal)

Answer (score 4):

Observe that
$$(A-I)(A^*-I)=AA^*-A-A^*+I=I$$
This means that $A-I$ and $A^*-I$ are inverses of each other.
It follows that
$$I=(A^*-I)(A-I)=A^*A-A-A^*+I$$
The desired conclusion follows.

---

A more general result can be shown to be true. Proceeding along the same lines, one can show that if $AB=A+B$, then $AB=BA$.